# Tricycle wheels won't turn when pedaling

Tags: wheels, pedals, tricycle

I have a tricycle that I just changed the tubes on all wheels. Went to ride it and the pedals will just turn but not engage the chain or wheels.

Chain is on correctly, wheels are on the same side as before the tube changes and set to the right rotation direction.

When I take the wheel off that should be turning, all the nuts/washers were loose. Tightened them down and still nothing.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you take the axle out of the frame while you were working on the wheels?  What happens if you try to pedal backwards?

Comment: A photo might help show the problem.  And, does the driven wheel rotate if you push it by hand while off the ground?  Does the trike roll on the ground if you push it by hand ?

Comment: I didn't take the axle out. Pedaling backwards the pedals just move, the chain doesn't. The driven wheel will rotate and it does roll just fine, nothing locking up. For what's it's worth, this is one of those Margaritaville Trikes, not a recumbent at all.

Comment: Looks like that model has a cover over the chain. Can you look under it and see if the chain is on the teeth of the chainring (the front gear near the pedals)?

Comment: It is, the chain is on all the gears. I did notice this weekend that when I took the drive wheel off, that it doesn't seem to go a far into the axle as the other wheel. That and the nuts on that side of the axle are loose. Tried to tighten them but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: We need a picture of the chain/gears side of the bike. I suspect the chain is off of the chainring/front sprocket.

Comment: @carrie Did you get any photos to add to this question?